# AJAX returning a white space from PHP echo

Tags: javascript, php

This is a problem I been having several times, and I always ignore because I cant find a solution.

Basically every time I echoed a value back to Javascript using AJAX, the first value will contain a space (extra character) this is annoying because if I want to check if that value exist sometimes I cant due to the space.

Normally the values returned is something like this

```
 Value1
Value2
Value3
```

Here is the code below. I suggest to ignore the function **seperate_ajx_data** as I dont think the problem is located there.

**results[0]** is giving a white space plus the value!
What could be the issue of having a space in the first value?

PHP code:

```
$machine = null;
$sql = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT......");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){
    $machine .= $row['MACHINE']."+";
    $machine .= $row['COUNT(MACHINE)']."/";
}
echo $machine;
```

JavaScript code:

```
function get_machine_vals(id){
    var ht = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var url = "....";
    var val = "....="+id;
    ht.open("POST", url, true);
    ht.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    ht.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if(ht.readyState == 4 && ht.status == 200){
            var val = ht.responseText;
            var results = seperate_ajx_data(["/","+"],val);
            var el = document.getElementById("machine_dropdown");
            var opts = el.options;
            for(var i =0;i<results.length;i++){
                var tmp = results[i];
                alert(tmp + " " + tmp.length);
                switch (results[i]){
                    case "Test":
                        opts[0].innerHTML = "Seko "+results[i+1];
                        break;
                }
            }

        }
    };
    ht.send(val);
}

function seperate_ajx_data(symbols, val){
  var tmp_storage = [];
  var tmp_spliter = val.split(symbols[0]);
  var results = [];
  for(var x = 0;x<tmp_spliter.length;x++){
    tmp_storage = tmp_spliter[x].split(symbols[1]);
    for(var y = 0;y<tmp_storage.length;y++){
        results.push(tmp_storage[y]);
    }
  }
  return results;
}
```

Comment: You could `trim()` or `.trim()` the value.

Comment: I suggest you read up on JSON. Little more complex, but once you understand it, a millions times more flexible and with a lot less quirks (likes starting/trailing spaces).

Comment: @Federico the PHP code is the top bit of the code, there is nothing else valuable to share from my PHP file

Comment: Make sure you dont have a space before the php opening tag

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is unfortunately one of those "gotchas" when working with PHP.  The errant character might come from a space after a closing PHP tag.  A contrived example:

```
<?php

 ... do some work ...

?> <?php

... do some work, but note errant space between the tags
```

Possible fixes?

- Don't close the PHP tag
- Use a different transfer mechanism that is space-tolerant, for example JSON or XML.
- Strip (or "trim") your values client side.  In context of your code:

  ```
   var val = (ht.responseText || '').trim();
  ```

Answer (score 2):

Just check your opening `<?php` brackets, there might be a space (i've seen this before).

Answer (score 0):

It happened with me today. And unlike other answers related to opening bracket, for me it was the space after the closing bracket.

```
<?php
.....


?>[space][space][space]
```

I removed the spaces. And solved the issue.

Comment: should have removed the closing tag

Comment: How it's "unlike other answers" if the accepted answer literally says "The errant character might come from a space after a closing PHP tag"?